# reRendering Tweet Button on JSF

Tags: java, jsf, twitter

I'm following Twitter website to create a Tweet Button on my own website.
The problem is, when I reRender the page, it reRenders the button too, and I don't know 
why, but the button just disappears.

I'm using JSF 1.2

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
                    data-url="http://www.mywebsite.com" 
                    data-text="My Text"
                    data-count="vertical" 
                    data-via="MyTwitter">Tweet
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"/></a>
```

Before
[image]

after
[image]

Comment: I have the impression that this is browser specific. Which ones did you try? Dit it fail the same way on all?

Comment: only tried on chrome.. i'll try in another one..

Comment: i switched implementation to <iframe> and it's working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?counturl=http://www.mywebsite.com&amp;count=vertical&amp;via=mytwitter&amp;text=My%20Text&amp;url=http://www.mywebsite.com&amp;"
                        style="width:55px; height:65px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;" />
```

By doing this, reRender will not affect the button.